# ¿Cómo paso los datos de una variable a un arreglo, usando python?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

Deseo comparar dos archivos `excel` y las filas iguales copiar a otro archivo `excel`.

Estoy haciendo con este código, pero solo copia la última fila ¿Alguien sabe como solucionar el problema

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
path_base="D:/BU/base/Chips entregadosUnido.xlsx "
path_comparar="D:/BU/base/CONECTIVIDAD-2125-TDRP.xlsx"
path_resultado="D:/BU/base/Comparado.xlsx"
#workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('D:/BU/base/Comparado.xlsx')
#worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
file_base=xlrd.open_workbook(path_base) 
file_comparado=xlrd.open_workbook(path_comparar) 
#file_resultado=xlrd.open_workbook(path_resultado) 

shet_base=file_base.sheet_by_name("final")
shet_comparado=file_comparado.sheet_by_name("CONECTIVIDAD")
#shet_resultado=file_resultado.sheet_by_name("Hoja1")
print(shet_comparado.nrows)
print(shet_base.ncols)

count=0
for i in range(shet_base.nrows):
    for j in range(shet_comparado.nrows):
        if  shet_base.cell_value(i,0)== shet_comparado.cell_value(j,0):
            r=shet_comparado.cell_value(j,0),shet_comparado.cell_value(j,1)           
            print(r)
            count=count+1
           
df = pd.DataFrame(r).T
df.to_excel(excel_writer =path_resultado)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que cuando tus for terminan, toman el ultimo valor que recorrio el ciclo
Lo que pudieras hacer es crear una lista y esta pasarla al dataframe

```
listad = []
count=0
for i in range(shet_base.nrows):
    for j in range(shet_comparado.nrows):
        if  shet_base.cell_value(i,0)== shet_comparado.cell_value(j,0):
            r = shet_comparado.cell_value(j,0),shet_comparado.cell_value(j,1)           
            listad.append(r)
            print(r)
            count=count+1
```

ahora si puedes pasar los valores a tu dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(listad).T
df.to_excel(excel_writer =path_resultado)
print(count)
```

recorrer dataframe por index

```
for i in listad.index:
    print(listad['nombredetucampo'][i])
```

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegra que te ayudara, podrias poner la respuesta como solucion, asi los demas podran saber mas rapidamente que fue de ayuda

Comment: `listad = []
count=0
for i in range(shet_base.nrows):
    for j in range(shet_comparado.nrows):
        if  shet_base.cell_value(i,0)== shet_comparado.cell_value(j,0):
             for k in range(shet_comparado.ncols):
                ** r = shet_comparado.cell_value(j,k)**           
                 listad.append(r)
                 count=count+1

df = pd.DataFrame(listad)
df.columns = ['Cedula','Nombres Apellidos']
df.to_excel(excel_writer =path_resultado)
print('\n', 'Cantidad:', count)`   Necesito  recorrer  las columnas de mi archivo agregue esta línea de código en negrita.

Comment: podrias agregarlo a la pregunta, o crear una nueva pregunto porque le codigo no es legible , pero para recorrer un dataframe tendrias que hacer por index

Comment: ya realice otra pregunta, ayude ahí por favor

Comment: te comente en la solucion

Comment: r = shet_comparado.cell_value(j,0),shet_comparado.cell_value(j,1)  esto me sirve para copiar dos columnas, pero si tengo n columnas no me sirve, eso de recorrer el dataframe no entiendo  la verdad, la idea es recorrer las n columnas de archivo excel y pasar a la lista, no si me hago entender, gracias.